# Inverse Quantum Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space

In the quantum harmonic oscillator problem, how would one go about calculating

$$\left\langle n\left|\frac{1}{X^2}\right|n\right\rangle$$

using raising and lowering operators $a^{\dagger}, a$ only, where $X\propto a + a^{\dagger}$ is a linear combination of the raising and lowering operators?

It would also be helpful if someone could refer me to materials on properties of functions of quantum operators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The operator $X^{-2}$ does exist and is self-adjoint as it follows from standard spectral theory. Its domain is  $$D(X^{-2}) := \left\{\psi \in L^2(\mathbb R, dx) \:\left|\: \int_{\mathbb R} x^{-4} |\psi(x)|^2 dx \right.< +\infty\right\}$$ and thereon
$$(X^{-2}\psi)(x) := x^{-2}\psi(x)\:.$$
The eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian operator of the harmonic oscillator are of the form $\psi_n(x) = H_n(x) e^{-x^2/2}$ (with  ``normalized'' values of the physical quantities, $m,\omega, \hbar$ appearing in the formula of Hamiltonian), where $H_n$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Therefore only polynomials $H_n$ which can be factorized as $x^2Q_n(x)$ where $Q_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-2$  define elements of $D(X^{-2})$. The $H_n$ are the  the well-known **Hermite polynomials**. It is known that $H_{2n}(0) \neq 0$ and $H_{2n-1}(x)$ tends to $0$ with the same order as $x$ for $x\to 0$. Therefore no $\psi_n$ belongs to $D(X^{-2})$ and $\langle \psi_n|X^{-2}\psi_n\rangle$ does not exist.

The use of the operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$ is delicate and, in a sense, dangerous for these type of mathematical problems, because identities like $$X^n= c^n(a+a^\dagger)^n$$
only hold in a *subdomain* $D$ of $D(X^n)$ given by the (dense) finite span of all functions $\psi_n$, even if the restriction of $X^n$ to that subdomain completely determins $X^n$ itself (as $D$ is a *core* of $X^n$).

However, I suspect that you are interested in $\langle X^{-2} \rangle_{\psi_n}$,i.e., *the expectation value of $X^{-2}$ in the state representaed by $\psi_n$*.

To this end it is worth stressing that, **if $\psi \in D(A)$** (and I henceforth assume that $\psi$ is normalized) then $$\langle A\rangle_\psi = \langle \psi| A \psi\rangle\:.\tag{1}$$
However, the general definition of $\langle A\rangle_\psi$ does not require $\psi \in D(A)$, but  $\psi \in D(\sqrt{|A|})$ is sufficient and in this case
$$\langle A \rangle_\psi := \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda d\mu^{(A)}_{\psi}(\lambda)\tag{2}\:,$$
where $\mu^{(A)}_{\psi}(E) := \langle \psi| P^{(A)}(E)\psi \rangle$
with $E\subset \sigma(A) \subset \mathbb R$ a Borel set and $P^{(A)}$ the spectral measure of $A$, so that $A = \int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda dP^{(A)}(\lambda)$. If $\psi \in D(A)$ which is a subset of $D(\sqrt{|A|})$, it turns out that, as theoretical physicists assume from scratch, (1) holds true,
howerver the true definition of $\langle A \rangle_\psi$ is (2).

In the considered case where $A= X^{-2}$, using the given definitions one finds
$$\langle X^{-2} \rangle_\psi := \int_{\mathbb R} x^{-2} |\psi(x)|^2 dx$$
provided the integrand is absolutely integrable which means $\psi \in D(\sqrt{|X^{-2}|})$. This is the case for $n= 2k+1$ when $\psi=\psi_n$ because $x^{-2} |\psi_{2k+1}(x)|^2$ is bounded in a neighborood of $x=0$ as said above.

Assuming it, one may go on formally. For instance (with $c$ as above)
$$\langle X^{-2} \rangle_{\psi_{1}} = c^{-2} \langle \psi_0| a \frac{1}{(a+a^\dagger)^2} a^\dagger \psi_0 \rangle = c^{-2} \langle \psi_0| (a+ a^\dagger) \frac{1}{(a+ a^\dagger)^2} (a+ a^\dagger) \psi_0 \rangle = c^{-2} \langle \psi_0|\psi_0\rangle =c^{-2}$$
The computation of $\langle X^{-2} \rangle_{\psi_{2k+1}}$ can be arranged similarly starting from
$$\langle X^{-2} \rangle_{\psi_{2n+1}} = \frac{c^{-2}}{2n+1} \langle \psi_0| (a+a^\dagger) a^{2n} \frac{1}{(a+a^\dagger)^2} (a^{\dagger})^{2n}(a+a^\dagger)\psi_0\rangle$$
and taking advantage of CCR.

Comment: While this seems mathematically sound, this is the first time I see a physical observable defined only for a subspace of the hilbert space (in your case you divide the hilbert space into even and odd under parity and define the operator only for the odd part). I know of operators that only act non trivially on a certain subspace, but should be defined for all the space. So in what sense is $X^{-1}$ an inverse of $X$? can a matrix have an inverse only for some of its entries? Sorry for mixing too much physical intuition with mathematical rigor, but physicists are usually guilty of this

Comment: It is easy: The spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of an observable $A$ consists of the outcomes of measurements, if these are an unbouded set, $A$ itself is unbounded since $||A||= \sup\{|x| | x \in \sigma(A)\}$. A well-known theorem establishes that a self-adjoint operator is defined on the whole Hilbert space if and only if it is bounded. So most QM self-adjoint operators like $X$ and $P$ cannot be defined on the whole Hilbert space but just on a dense domain as their spectrum is unbounded for physical reasons...

Comment: $X^{-1}$ satisfies $X^{-1}X\psi = \psi$ if $\psi \in D(X)$, since $X$ is injective on its domain...

Comment: ...Obviously, it also holds $XX^{-1}\psi =\psi$ for $\psi \in D(X^{-1})$.

Comment: If you deal with matrices (finite matrices), you cannot see the problem as they are everywhere defined.

Answer (score 0):

when we define $X=a+ a^\dagger$, $\frac{1}{X}$ and any power thereof do not exist.

Proof:

Consider the state $\left|x\right\rangle\propto e^{-a^{\dagger 2} + 2 x\, a^\dagger}\left| 0\right\rangle$, you can show that $X\left|x\right\rangle = x \left|x\right\rangle$, and in particular if you choose $x=0$, then $X\left|x=0\right\rangle = 0$.

Now from elementary linear algebra, an operator with a zero eigenvalue is singular and non-invertible, that is $X^{-1}$ does not exist.

edit: if we gloss over the abstract question of invertibility (because of the subtleties of the infinite hilbert space), you can look at $$X^{-1}X=1$$
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow X^{-1}&\left|1\right\rangle = \left|0\right\rangle\\
 X^{-1}&\left(\left|0\right\rangle+\sqrt{2}\left|2\right\rangle \right) = \left|1\right\rangle \\
 X^{-1}&\left(\sqrt{2}\left|1\right\rangle+\sqrt{3}\left|3\right\rangle \right) = \left|2\right\rangle \\
\ldots
\end{align}
to convince your self that these conditions are mutually incompatible, in the sense that you cannot write an expansion in powers of $a$ and $a^\dagger$ that would satisfy this conditions. (equivalently write down $\left\langle n |X|n'\right\rangle$ in matrix form and convince yourself you cannot multiply it by any matrix that gives unity)

Comment: I first thought this, too, but the state $\lvert x \rangle$ is not a valid state in the Hilbert space, i.e. it is not a proper eigenvector of $x$, but only lies inside the larger part of a rigged Hilbert space. It is not clear that the existence of a zero eigenvector *in a larger space* forbids the invertibility on the Hilbert space.

Comment: right, one basis is countable and one is not. I edited the answer to provide a practical demonstration rather than an abstract argument

Answer (score 0):

Ali Moh's answer is nice. Here is a different perspective.

Let me just completely forget about creation and annhilation operators and try to construct this matrix element using the wave function for the harmonic oscillator. I'll interpret $X$ as the position operator (since that seems like what you have in mind).

Then let's take a look at this expectation value in the ground state
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_0 = \langle 0 | \frac{1}{X^2} | 0 \rangle
\end{equation}
The ground state wave function is $\langle x | 0 \rangle = \psi(x) = \pi^{-1/4} e^{-x^2/2}$. So
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_0 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \psi^*(x) \frac{1}{x^2} \psi(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\infty dx \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2}
\end{equation}
This integral diverges. To see this we can put in a cutoff on the lower bound:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_0[\epsilon] = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2} = 2\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon} - \sqrt{\pi} + O(\epsilon)\right) 
\end{equation}
To me this looks related to the problem that Ali Moh identified, in that $|x\rangle$ is a zero eigenvector of $X$ so we have to be careful near $x=0$.
Empirically (ie, trying out the first 10 or so on mathematica), it looks like the integral diverges for all even $n$. (The odd $n$ expectation values are just zero, because the wave function is odd in that case).

An alternative approach is to regulate your operator in such a way that it is inverible. That is, instead of inverting $X^2$, let's invert $X^2 + \ell^2$, where $\ell$ is a constant with dimensions of length.

Then
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{E}_0 = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{x^2 + \ell^2} = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\ell} + \cdots
\end{equation}
This is just a different way to regularize the integral, but I think in this form it is more clear that the problem is with the operator $1/X^2$ being singular.